# IntelliJ, Groovy, Jenkins, and unresolved access

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a shared library that is used to run pipeline on jenkins.

Frequently I used things like:

```
def call(String stage_name = "Generate installer") {

        //noinspection GrUnresolvedAccess
        stage(stage_name) {
            ...
        }
}
```

`stage` is a Jenkins steps. It generate an "unresolved access" warning in IntelliJ because it's not declared everywhere. Hopefully it does not generate an error as if it was a missing class import.

However I do wonder if there's a better solution than putting suppress warning declarations. Is there any way to indicate to IntelliJ the existence of the Jenkins steps ?

Comment: Configure Groovy DSL for this, see http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2018/07/30/working-with-jenkinsfile-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: Thanks. I did it but it did not work. I am using a shared library. In my share I still have this warning: "Cannot resolve symbol 'echo'". If the workscript is passed as a variable (not in a DSL but in a class), then it consider 'echo' as a method and raises no warning. Even if it doesn't really knows that. Same in Jenkins file, also, Jenkins file do not see my shared methods, even if it is declared as a dependency.

Comment: So I finally made it to work thanks to you, the pipeline.gdsl generated had errors in strings.
However, some variables such as BUILD_NUMBER are not present in the gdsl, how can I fix that ?